# Parallel transport, vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $\mathbf{X}$ vector field along curve $\gamma: [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathcal{M}$. We can parallel transporated each vector $\mathbf{X}(t)$ in the point $\gamma(a)$. That is, we can get a set of vectors $P_t^a \mathbf{X}(t)$ in the tangent space $T_{\gamma (a)} M$. 
I read in the book that this set can be viewed as a vector field along map $ P \circ \gamma : [a, b] \longrightarrow  T_{\gamma (a)} M$.

I did not understand it. What exactly is a vector field? The map $P_t^a$? And what is the map P? And what is codomain? Codomain of vector field should be a tangent space of codomain map...

Sorry for my English

Here is this book, but there written on russian

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A *vector field* is a smooth section $s:M\to TM$ of the tangent bundle.  So if $\pi:TM\to M$ is the projection of the tangent bundle of $M$ onto $M$(takes each tangent space $T_pM$ to $p$), we have $\pi\circ s=id_M$.

[Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport) is a reference on parallel transport.

Secondly,  the [codomain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain)  may be familiar to you as the range of or target space of a function.  ( Though be careful:  range of $f$ can mean image of $f$.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know what a vector field and parallel translation are. I know what is $P_a^b$. I'm a little confused about $P$ and $P \circ \gamma$. And why $P_t^a$ can be viewed like vector field along $P \circ \gamma$.

Comment: How to copmose $P$ with $\gamma$? $P$ is defined on $\gamma ([a, b])$?

Comment: Sure.  $\gamma$ is a curve on $M$; and $P$ goes from $M$ to $TM$.

Comment: $P: M \to TM, \gamma(t) \mapsto v \in T_{\gamma(t)}$?

Comment: If it is right, why $P \circ \gamma$ act in $T_{\gamma(a)}$?

Comment: $TM=\cup_{p\in M} T_pM$.  Also, i think $P$ is only defined on $\gamma [a,b]\subset M$.  But, in any case, $P\circ\gamma (t)\in T_{\gamma (t)}M$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82440/discussion-between-simurgh-and-chris-custer).